# Create dataframe from row and colum indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Since my previous question went unanswered, I'll try again more simply.

I have a program which makes a list containing row and column indexes:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1] # row
b = [0, 1, 0, 1] # column
```

This can also be formatted as lists of list:

```
a = [[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]
```

Dataframe:

```
      Name  2544  2543  2542
0     DR01    13    16    23
1     DR02    15    27    12
2     DR03    16    18    13
3     DR04    17    92    56
```

Objective is to obtain the values from the dataframe mentioned based on indexes in list and create a new dataframe. I tried a for loop but that didn't work and was very slow.

What it should look like:

```
      Name  2544
0     DR01    13
1     DR02    15
```

Update:

Here is what I have tried:

```
In[96]: df = importDialog.df.iloc[a,b]
In[96]: print(df)

Out[96]:
      Name  2544    Name  2544
0     DR01    13    DR01    13
1     DR02    15    DR02    15
```

Also, when I try showing the complete dataset in a table:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 9.06 GiB for an array with shape (34749, 34992) and data type object
```

Comment: Can you please post what you tried and what the output was?

Comment: Are the indexes always create a rectangular shape?

Comment: @GlenvillePecor Done!

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm planning to add a condition that if the shape is not rectangular, an exception is raised. Could you help me with that?

Comment: How does your a with six pairs yield a 2x2 dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston Apologies, have updated correct values after running the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your checked that `a,b` constitute a rectangular shape:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 1] # row
b = [0, 1, 0, 1] # column

df.iloc[sorted(set(a)),sorted(set(b))]
```

Output:

```
   Name  2544
0  DR01    13
1  DR02    15
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, been breaking my head with this for almost 2 days. Two more thing, is there a way to do this if the shape is not rectangular? and how would I check if the shape is not rectangular?

Comment: `len(a) == len(set(a)) * len(set(b))`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again. Would vote your answer up, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Also, you need to check if `a,b` have same length, which might not be the case from your error message.